# Counting related rows in a child table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have been trying to do some queries and getting a count on related tables using eloquent.

Tables:

- requests
- contact (belongs to requests)
- history (belongs to contact)

As such X number of requests each have Y number of contacts which in term each have Z number of histories

Using sql I can do something like this to get all the counts.

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
         SELECT count(contact.id)
         FROM contact 
         WHERE contact.requests_id = requests.id
    ) AS n_contact,
    (
         SELECT count(history.id)
         FROM contact INNER JOIN history ON (history.contact_id = contact.id)
         WHERE contact.requests_id = requests.id
    ) AS n_history
FROM requests;
```

[image: Above Query]

But I am a bit lost when using eloquent to build queries. If for instance I was selecting all contacts for a given request at what point would I join/count the history? Or do I need to add in some accessor's into the relevant Models for these 3 tables?

```
public function getAllContacts($id) {
    return Requests::where('requests.id', '=', $id)
            ->join('requests', 'contact.requests_id', '=', 'requests.id')
            ->select('contact.*', 'requests.name');
            ->get();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You want to count Z per Y and Y per X, Z per X or what exactly?

Comment: I wanted to get a count of all Z per X, and all Z per Y. So given a specific Z or X I could get a count of Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use helper relation for this, if you'd like to use Eloquent instead of manual joins:

```
// Request model
public function contactsCount()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Contact')->selectRaw('request_id, count(*) as aggregate')->groupBy('request_id');
}

public function getContactsCountAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('contactsCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('contactsCount');

    return $this->getRelation('contactsCount')->aggregate;
}
```

The same would go for `Contact` model towards `History` model.

For counting far relation (`Request` -> `History`) you can use `hasManyThrough` relation with a little adjustment.

This way you can eager load those aggregates for multiple models without n+1 issue, nice and easy:

```
$requests = Request::with('contactsCount', 'contacts.historyCount')->get();
// 1 query for reuqests, 1 query for contacts count and 2 queries for contacts.historyCount

// example output
$requests->first()->contactsCount; // 17
$requests->first()->contacts->first()->historyCount; // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Make Relation in the Request Model */

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Contact', 'request_id', 'id');
}
```

/* use `withCount()` to get the total numner of contacts */

```
public function getAllContacts($id) {
    return Requests::with('contacts')
            ->withCount('contacts')
            ->find($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more simplified is in models requests, first get childs info then use count() function

```php
    //--In requests model
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(contacts::class);
    }
    public function contactsCnt() {
        return $this->contacts()->count();
    }


    //-- And in contacts model
    public function history()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(history::class);
    }
    public function historyCnt() {
        return $this->history()->count();
    }
```